# "Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources ..." happened in simple transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

In very rare situations, I got an Exception in my Delphi program, which is showing following problem with SQL Server 2012:

> Transaction (Process ID xxx) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the
>   transaction

I [read about deadlocks](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx) and I think I do understand under which circumstances a deadlock can occur.

The transaction which failed looked like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT currentVal FROM numbers where ID = ...
UPDATE numbers SET currentVal = currentVal + 1 where ID = ...  // <-- Exception here
COMMIT
```

The stacktrace of my application showed that the error happened in the UPDATE statement, not during the COMMIT.

I do not understand how this transaction could cause a deadlock.
The UPDATE could force other transactions to wait, but only for a short time, since the UPDATE clause will end normally, without the transaction having to wait for the other transaction which is waiting.

Triggers are not present.

Does anybody have a hint what did happen in this transaction and if there is anything I can improve?

Comment: please share deadlock graph as xml

Comment: you can use below link to get deadlock trace, this works  ,even when you don't have trace enabled :https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10646/31995

Comment: It happened only 2 times in the last few years, and not even on my development machine; I don't have a trace/deadlock graph I'm afraid. I was trying to find the cause by looking at the code, since this transaction seems to be too simple to fail.

Comment: it doesn't work like that, you need to have trace to proceeed further

Comment: what is your transaction isolation level? If `read commited` what is value of option `READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Do you have any index on your `ID` column? What is your clustered index key? I'm afraid that there is a scan operation due to unoptimized queries which aquires more shared locks than you thought. If there is a scan operation, your code is likely to blocked if executed by multiple sessions at the same time

Comment: @KhanhTO Yes, the column has an index. The table structure is this : https://pastebin.com/Vv8D9VpX . Is there something that could be improved in regards this problem?

Comment: I cannot access your url. Is it a clustered index on ID?

Comment: @KhanhTO Thank you for your reply. Yes, it is. Its definition is `CONSTRAINT [PK_NUMBERS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]` also it is worth mentioning that ID is a varchar.